# getting id of page

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am using taxonomy.php to display records from database. The function get_the_ID() in taxonomy.php gives the ID of first record from database.

My URL is http://www.example.com/taxonomy_name/page_slug.

I also tried :

```
global $post;
$post->id;
```

It is also giving ID of first record from database.

How to get the ID of page?

Comment: PHP is case-sensitive.  `$post->ID` is the current post's ID.

Comment: $post->ID also gives same result.

Comment: I think you should rename `page_slug` with `term_slug` in your url example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
$qobj = get_queried_object();
var_dump($qobj->term_id);
```

[`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will get information about the current page. That information varies by type and content for different pages but on a taxonomy page it will give you a stdClass object with taxonomy data related to that page..

Comment: $qobj->term_id is giving the term id from table wp_terms, I need the ID of page whose slug i am using in URL.  http://www.example.com/taxonomy_name/page_slug.

Comment: found it - found it - <?php $my_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$slug'"); ?>

Comment: Your question implies that you are already on a taxonomy page. If so, the extra database query is unnecessary.